# What is if (c != EOF) used for in reverse Polish calculater

Tags: c, eof

I'm learning The C Programming language.

In below code

```
#include <ctype.h>
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    while((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';

    if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c;
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c))
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))           ;
    if(c == '.')
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))           ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if(c != EOF)
      ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER; 
}

#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

int getch(void)
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

I think statement `if（c != EOF)` in `getop()` is unnecessary.

In standard input, each line consists of zero or more characters followed by a newline character.

When the statement executes,what c has fetched follows a digit character or a `.`,in which situation c could be a newline character or other characters except for `EOF`.

It is clear that `c` is not `EOF` without testing.

What is `if(c != EOF)` used for?

Sorry if this is a trivial question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's `EOF c != if`.

Comment: Standard input is not guaranteed to end with a newline. Just press ^D in the middle of a line (on UNIX/Linux).

Comment: The standard input does not necessarily consist of lines. It may well be a uniform stream of characters. On most modern OSs it is. Any character is permitted at any position. Your application may it as a sequence of lines or as something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

> In standard input, each line consists of zero or more characters followed by a newline character.

Not necessarily; the input is an arbitrary byte stream and does not have to end with a newline character.

> When the statement executes,what c has fetched follows a digit character or a .,in which situation c could be a newline character or other characters except for EOF.

It could be EOF, also.

> It is clear that c is not EOF without testing.

No it isn't; in fact, it is clear that c might be EOF.

> What is if(c != EOF) used for?

To prevent ungetch(EOF), which is undefined because EOF can't be crammed into buf.

P.S. The program has undefined behavior if it does read EOF, or if the input stream contains values outside of the positive part of the range of char ... the argument to isdigit should always be an int, but it's a char here.